# Running local NodeJS application can't connect to MySQL docker container running locally

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, networking, containers

I have an SQL docker container running on my host using docker-compose.

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -p
```

This works perfectly.
But...

When I am in my host trying to connect to it using my NodeJS app it fails -

````
            client: 'mysql2',
            connection: dbSsl ? async () => {
                const token  = await rds.getAuthPluginPromise();
                return {
                    host : 127.0.0.1,
                    port : 3306,
                    user : root,
                    ssl: "",
                    database : "myapp",
                    multipleStatements: true,
                    authPlugins: {
                        mysql_clear_password: () => () => {
                            return Buffer.from(token + '\0')
                        }
                    }
                };
            } : databaseUrl,
            pool: {min: dbPoolMin, max: dbPoolMax, propagateCreateError: false},
            searchPath: "myapp",
            requestTimeout: 30000,
        });```
````

docker compose

```
      mysql:
    image: arm64v8/mysql:oracle
    container_name: mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "password"
```

````
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                               NAMES
6369b421dc7d   arm64v8/mysql:oracle   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 minutes ago   Up 3 minutes   0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp   mysql```
````

Comment: Sorry it doesn't make sense how do you run your Node application. If Node lives in docker please provide the configs. Add more details about your app, so that we can discuss.

Comment: The nodejs runs locally.
And I try to connect to mysql locally and I succeed..
Added the code to the main thread :)
@igobr

Comment: Thank you, now please `console.log` your variables such as `dbHost`, `dbUser`, `dbSsl`, `dbSchema`. We need to know the values :)

Comment: @igobr - done.
Edited the values in the chat.

Comment: I have posted the answer below. I understand you copied the values over your code but please add quotes around 127.0.0.1 not to confuse other readers. You need `return ... host: "127.0.0.1", ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, you miss some environment variables in your container.
Try adding the following:

```yaml
mysql:
  image: arm64v8/mysql:oracle
  container_name: mysql
  restart: always
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "password"
    MYSQL_DATABASE: "myapp"               ### <-- you need this one at least
```

Also, try adding more debug in your code. Just right after your server starts, try something like:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "password",
  database : "myapp"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});
```

If this works, then debug the code you published in your question.

Comment: Tried adding MYSQL_DATABASE.
Still not wokring.
But what's odd, that if I'm on my shell and do mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u root -ppassword and it works. Why my shell local works, but locally debugging with my intellij it doesn't connect..

Comment: @EilonA I updated my answer, please check

Comment: The issue was that I connected to a wrong database.. myapp wasn't my database